# Heroku restart = Resource not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shell, deployment, heroku

I'm using Heroku to deploy a Rails3 App for months.

Until now, deploying my app was really straightforward.. (I'm using heroku san to manage environments like staging or production) .. but today, the command "restart" give me a nice "Resource not found" error.

I can't understand why because the others commands works (console, rake db:migrate, ...)

Good :

```
heroku console --app my_app  
heroku rake db:migrate --app my_app  
heroku stack --app my_app  
etc...
```

Not good :

```
heroku restart --app my_app
```

Any suggestions ?
Thx.

---

Here's the full Terminal command and result :

```
me@computer:my_app_folder(master)$ heroku restart --app my_app
Resource not found
```

There's nothing else...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the specific error message?

Comment: Done, but it is still synthetic...

Comment: Try running `heroku bundle install --app my_app`. I would write Heroku support about this.

Comment: Thx for your answer, the error has gone away after a nice `gem update heroku`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was obvious...

```
gem update heroku
```

The update fix this issue. Here's my gems versions :

```
heroku (2.4.2, 1.17.10)
heroku_san (1.2.3, 1.2.0)
```